# How predecessor deal with the margin collapse with css1.0

Tags: html, css

I search on css1.0 and css2.1 specification:

css1.0 : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#formatting-model

css2.1 : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow

I find there is BFC(block formatting context) on css2.1.But,there is no BFC on css1.0.I am confused.How predecessor deal with the margin collapse with css1.0.

Comment: I know ,there is overflow : hidden , display : table ...to deal with margin collapse.Because they all trigger BFC . But, there is no bfc  in the old days.How they deal with this problem.

Comment: there was zoom:1; look about `haslayout` and internet Explorer .... clear was avalaible to clear floatting elements, overflow worked in FF1, but not in IE6 if i do remember correctly . I do not remenber about BFC definition at this time . had my first computer in 92 and minded website around 2004 ...

Comment: @G-Cyr how you deal with height collapse when the div contains float div  element in the old days?how you make the div height auto to conclude float div element?Thank you.

Comment: At that time, webmaster used massively tables to build layout to deal with theses things and columns layout. You also had tons of the  translucide spacer.gif to clear floatting elements.....